# AngularJS override resource dependency of service to be unit tested with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, jasmine, karma-runner

I have created a custom ngResource which prepends the API_END_POINT to the url. This works fine so far. But for the unit tests I would like to override the customResource with the standard ngResource. The following code works but how can I override the customResource dependency after calling service = $injector.get('svcSecurity') ?

**Service:**

```
angular.module('common.security.service', ['common.resource'])

.factory('svcSecurity', ['customResource', function($resource) { 
    var service = {
        // Attempt to authenticate a user by the given email and password
        login: function(email, password) {
            return $resource('/login').save({}, {email: email, password: password}, function(response){
                alert(response.success);
            }, function(ex) {
                alert("exception");
            });
        },       
    };
    return service;
}]);
```

**Resource:**

```
angular.module('common.resource', ['common.configuration', 'ngResource'])

// http://kirkbushell.me/angular-js-using-ng-resource-in-a-more-restful-manner/

.factory('customResource', ['$resource', 'API_END_POINT', function($resource, API_END_POINT) {
    return function(url, params, methods) {
        // prepend API_END_POINT to url
        var resource = $resource(API_END_POINT + url, params, methods);
        //var resource = $resource(url, params, methods);

        return resource;
    };
}]);
```

**Unit test:**

```
describe('common.security.service', function() {
    beforeEach(module('common.security.service'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');   
        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');        
        service = $injector.get('svcSecurity');
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });    

    describe('login', function() {
        it('sends a http request to login the specified user', function() {          
            $httpBackend.when('POST', 'http://localhost/api/login').respond(200, {success: 'true'});
            $httpBackend.expect('POST', 'http://localhost/api/login');
            service.login('email', 'password');
            $httpBackend.flush();
        });
    });
});
```

Based on [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend) it is possible for controllers to be instanciated like this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
 // Set up the mock http service responses
 $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
 // backend definition common for all tests
 $httpBackend.when('GET', '/auth.py').respond({userId: 'userX'}, {'A-Token': 'xxx'});

 // Get hold of a scope (i.e. the root scope)
 $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
 // The $controller service is used to create instances of controllers
 var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

 createController = function() {
   return $controller('MyController', {'$scope' : $rootScope });
 };
}));
```

It would be great if I could do this with my service and pass ngResource as parameter.

Answer (score 4):

You can register other providers to test a service

Check out the $provide documentation [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$provide](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide)

It's useful to use your own mocks of other services. By doing so, you can test your service in isolation of other dependencies.

In your test you can do it by passing a function as second parameter to the module function and set up your mock there, which, in your case, will be the $resource service.

```
beforeEach(module('common.security.service', function($provide) {
    $provide.provide('svcSecurity', function() {
        this.$get = function($resource) {
            return $resource
        }
    })
}));
```